# Can I make a Perl subclass without implementing a child constructor?

Tags: perl

Is it possible in Perl to make a subclass without implementing a constructor? I don't need any subclass-specific constructor behaviour, so I'd like to inherit from the parent.

In this example, I have a base class `Base.pm` and a child class `Child.pm`. The `Child` class should simply override one of its parent's methods:

```
# test.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Child;

my $o = Child->new();
$o->exec();
```

-

```
# Base.pm
package Base;

sub new{
    my $self = {};

    bless $self;
    return $self;
}

sub exec{
    my $self = shift;
    die "I'm in the Base class\n";
}

1;
```

-

```
# Child.pm
package Child;

use Base;
@ISA = ('Base');

sub exec{
    my $self = shift;

    die "OVERRIDE in child\n";
}

1;
```

When I run test.pl, the *Base class's* exec method gets executed (I assume it's because the object gets blessed as `Base` in the `Base.pm` constructor).

```
$ ./test.pl 
I'm the Base class
```

Is there a way to implement a child class without having to reimplement a constructor?

Comment: Also see [`Inheritance--Writing Constructors in perlobj`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Writing-Constructors)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

You effectively have the following:

```
sub new {
   return bless({});
}
```

Replace it with the following:

```
sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   return bless({}, $class);
}
```

Basically, always use [`bless`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html)'s two-argument form.

---

How I write my constructors:

- Base classes:

  ```
  sub new {
     my ($class, ...) = @_;
     my $self = bless({}, $class);
     $self->{...} = ...;
     return $self;
  }
  ```
- Derived classes:

  ```
  sub new {
     my ($class, ...) = @_;
     my $self = $class->SUPER::new(...);
     $self->{...} = ...;
     return $self;
  }
  ```

I like the symmetry.